# How to `flutter run` just for my architecture?

Tags: flutter

My flutter app is of course multiarchitecture and uses Rust code.

Curerently, when I do `flutter run`, it rebuild the Rust library for x86_64 and aarch64, even though I'm running on a phone with just aarch64 (or couse).

Is there a way to build the native binaries only for the phone target?

Answer (score -1):

Hey if you want to split your output build for architecture wise, then you can use `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` command.

Comment: I need to actually just build my architecture when runnning `flutter run`

Comment: In my knowledge there is nothing to run app for specific arm instead of build

Comment: You can try with setting default abi in your gradle file but i am not sure it will meet your requirement or not. Have look into this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984644/how-to-specify-supported-architectures-for-android-app-in-build-gradle